# the meaning of “accounting for designs ” and trim

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Supplier shall maintain records, including but not limited to, accounting for designs, labels, trims, packing materials and hangtags,

context:used to produce a clothing record.

What are the meanings of "accounting for designs" and "trims" in this sentence?

According to the dictionary, *accounting* means bookkeeper, but this is not the right meaning in this context. *Trim* means repair. This too is not right meaning here.

I am still confused about the meaning.

Comment: You need to ask a lawyer what it means, since it is legal language. We really can't undertake to advise you in such matters here.

Comment: This isn't really a legal question, but the question is still fairly basic. There are multiple meanings of words. If your dictionary only tells you one then you need a better dictionary.

Comment: Which dictionary? I've never heard of *trim* meaning *repair*. Try OALD: *[account for](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/account-for)*; *[trim](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trim_2)*.

Answer (score 1):

The company setting the requirements is presumably buying clothing from the supplier, and they want to know everything that went into making the clothing and how much it cost.  An "accountant" is a bookkeeper; an "accounting" is the detailed records that a bookkeeper maintains.  The categories here of things to track have names that are terms of art in the industry:

- [labels](http://wunderlabel.com/gallery/woven-labels-with-your-logo), identifying tags, often of fabric and sewn into the garment.
- [trims](http://www.mjtrim.com/), any kind of decorative accessory such as lace, ribbons, buttons, etc.
- [hang tags](http://wunderlabel.com/hang-tags/standard?ht-type=text-qr#showht_type), temporary tags, usually paper stock, attached to a garment by a string, containing price, bar codes, etc.

However, grammar and usage can take you only so far.  As this sounds like part of a contract, your best bet is to consult a lawyer who is familiar with the industry and who can tell you what form and content is likely to satisfy the requirement.